# h264 error while decoding

Tags: opencv, camera, ffmpeg

I wanna get frames from my ip camera but same errors occured. I read some web page about that error but i couldnt solve the problem. I am using visual C++ 2010

Code :

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("rtsp://192.168.0.18:554/ucast/11");

  if (!capture.isOpened()) return 1;

  double width = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);  
  double height = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

  cv::namedWindow("showRTSP", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

  while (true) {

    cv::Mat frame;
    if (!capture.read(frame)) break;
    cv::imshow("showRTSP", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) break;
  }
```

Errors : [h264 @ 00000000030afaa0] error while decoding MB 59 10

thanks...

Comment: i solved the problem using VLC lib instead of videocapture() method.

Comment: can you give the details of how did you solve it as an answer? It would be nice.